# How to obtain correlation coefficients for every column pair in a dataframe with R?

Tags: r, for-loop

Here's some code:

```
for(i in 1:colCount){
 for(j in colCount:i){
     cor(newCovidNoNaDF[,i],newCovidNoNaDF[,j], method = "pearson")
 }
}
```

But nothing is output when I click enter. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `print()`?

Comment: `cor(newCovidNoNaDF)`

Comment: Thank you Martin. print() didn't work when I was working with a datatable earlier, so I figured it wouldnt with a dataframe. I was wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combn`. Taking `mtcars` as example :

```
val <- combn(seq_along(mtcars), 2, function(x) 
             cor(mtcars[[x[1]]], mtcars[[x[2]]], method = 'pearson'))
name <- combn(names(mtcars), 2, paste0, collapse = '-')
data <- data.frame(name, val)

head(data)

#      name        val
#1  mpg-cyl -0.8521620
#2 mpg-disp -0.8475514
#3   mpg-hp -0.7761684
#4 mpg-drat  0.6811719
#5   mpg-wt -0.8676594
#6 mpg-qsec  0.4186840
```

Answer (score 0):

The `correlate()` function from the `corrr` package computes pairwise column correlations for a dataframe:

```r
library(corrr)

correlate(df)
```

Output:

```r
Correlation method: 'pearson'
Missing treated using: 'pairwise.complete.obs'

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  term       a      b      c
  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 a     NA      0.182  0.223
2 b      0.182 NA     -0.262
3 c      0.223 -0.262 NA
```

Data:

```r
set.seed(123)
n <- 20
df <- tibble(a = rnorm(n), b = rnorm(n), c = rnorm(n))
```